# JavaScript Array[i] is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i will have this code in javascript

```
Players = [
    ["івлавіл", 0, "PersonId0"],
    ["івлавіл", 0, "PersonId1"],
    ["івлавіл", 0, "PersonId2"]
];

var boys = 0,
    girls = 0,
    counter = 0,
    ip,
    PlayersCount = Players.length;

for (ip = 0; ip < PlayersCount+1; ip++) {
    if (Players[ip][1] == 0) {
        boys++;
    }
    else if (Players[ip][1] == 1) {
        girls++;
    }
};
```

When i run this, i have this error "TypeError: Players[ip] is undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm debug this error alone;

i need change

`for(ip = 0; ip < PlayersCount+1; ip++)`

to

`for(ip = 0; ip < PlayersCount; ip++)`

Comment: This is the same as the answers that were given by Quentin and Nour Sammour. You should just accept one of their answers instead of posting your own duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ip < PlayersCount+1
> ```

Get rid of the `+1`. You're trying to read an extra item from the array.